# Raspberry with raspbian .profile accidentaly deleted

Tags: raspbian

I accidentally deleted my ./Profile from my pi user. How can I get it back?

Comment: Ok, I found the answer. The .profile is in /etc/skel/ so you can just copy it back to your home directory.

Comment: Then post that as an answer an accept it!

Answer (score 2):

Just copy `/etc/skel/.profile` to your home folder:

```
cp /etc/skel/.profile ~/
```